# How to rename this files

Tags: file, unix, rename

I have this series of files 1.dat, 2.dat, ..., 41.dat, qnd I want to rename all this files on scientific format like 0001.dat, 0002.dat, etc and all of that just using script command on unix.

Thank you for your response.

My best

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
for file in [0-9]*.txt; do     
  mv "$file" $(printf %04d.%s ${file%.*} ${file##*.})
done
```

**Test:**

```
$ touch 1.txt 2.txt 3.txt
$ ls
1.txt  2.txt  3.txt
$ for file in [0-9]*.txt; do     
mv "$file" $(printf %04d.%s ${file%.*} ${file##*.})
done
$ ls
0001.txt  0002.txt  0003.txt
```